# How do I delete the last member of a Redis sorted set?

Tags: redis

I am using a command line client. Looks like the ZREM doesn't help much. Now I wonder whether that is possible at all.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the element with the highest rank, use `zremrangebyrank <key> -1 -1`. Here's an example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test 1 one
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test 2 two
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test 3 three
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange test 0 -1
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "three"
127.0.0.1:6379> zremrangebyrank test -1 -1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange test 0 -1
1) "one"
2) "two"
```